# Idris: Type-Check Fail Because of 'rewrite__impl'

Tags: idris

I'm a beginner with Idris, and I'm trying to write a function that takes a `Vect n Type` and returns `{a : Vect n Type} -> type_1 -> ... -> type_n -> HVect (reverse a)`.  I've got it to type check down to the final recursive step, where it fails because of a `rewrite__impl` function stuck in the type.  Here's the code so far:

```
total funcGenerator : (Vect n Type) -> Type -> Type
funcGenerator []      out = out
funcGenerator (x::xs) out = x -> funcGenerator xs out

-- Reverse first argument, append second argument to it
total pileOn : Vect n Type -> Vect k Type -> Vect (plus n k) Type
pileOn               []      y = y
pileOn {n=S len} {k} (x::xs) y = rewrite plusSuccRightSucc len k in
                                     pileOn xs (x::y)

fetchArgsReverse : {h : Vect m Type} -> (b : Vect n Type) -> 
                   HVect h -> funcGenerator (HVect (pileOn b h))
fetchArgsReverse               [x]     y = (\p => p::y)
fetchArgsReverse {n=S len} {m} (x::xs) y = (\p => fetchArgsReverse xs (p::y))
```

The type checker complains like so:

```
|
| fetchArgsReverse {n=S len} {m} (x::xs) y = (\p => fetchArgsReverse xs (p::y))
|                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of fetchArgsReverse with expected type
    funcGenerator (x::xs) (HVect (pileOn (x::xs) h))

Type mismatch between
    funcGenerator xs (HVect (pileOn xs (x::h)))
        (Type of fetchArgsReverse xs (p::y))
and
    funcGenerator xs 
        (HVect (rewrite__impl (\replaced => Vect replaced Type)
        (plusSuccRightSucc len m) (pileOn xs (x::h)))) 
        (Expected Type)
```

(I've added some spacing.)

What do I do about this `rewrite__impl` in the expected type?  How do I resolve this issue?  The `pileOn` function does not work without the rewrite.